# The Server MUST process a second CONNECT Packet sent from a Client as a protocol violation and disconnect the old Client or the new Client?

Tags: mqtt

According to MQTT Protocol 3.1.1, "A Client can only send the CONNECT Packet once over a Network Connection. The Server MUST process a second CONNECT Packet sent from a Client as a protocol violation and disconnect the Client". But it confuses me that the server MUST disconnect the previous one or the new one?

I tested it with MQTT, and I used two sessions to subsribe the same topic with the same Client ID. Does it mean that the same client sends CONNECT twice? If it's true, it really confuses me.

The new subscriber'll cause the server disconnect the old one. It's diffirent with the protocol. When they old one disconnected, it'll try to send CONNECT and wait CONNACT packet. Then it turns to the new Client, and the server disconnects the previous new subscriber.....

So what does the protocol mean? The Server MUST process a second CONNECT Packet sent from a Client as a protocol violation and disconnect the old Client or the new Client?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing 2 separate events here.

Firstly if a single client sends 2 **connect** packets on the same network connection then the broker will disconnect that client.

The second instance you mention is 2 clients with the same client id. This will be 2 separate network connections even if from the same host.  Each of these clients will send a single **connect** packet but because there will be a client id clash the first of the clients to send the packet will be disconnect when the second arrives